# triangulating a sphere

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Can there be a triangulation of the sphere with $3$ triangles? We can start with the sphere and three vertices fixed. This divides the sphere into two triangles, which is illegal as the triangles would share more than two sides. Then if we add another vertex, we get four triangles, which is possible. Is there no way of obtaining three?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no possible way to triangulate the sphere using 3 vertices. Just like you cannot have two faces with the same three edges surrounding them, you cannot have two edges whose endpoints are the same two vertices. Said differently, a pair of vertices determine a unique edge in a triangulation. So with 3 vertices, the maximum number of edges possible is 3, which is not enough to triangulate the sphere.

Comment: Is this correct? In Example 4.14(i) of the book Complex Algebraic Curves, Kirwan claims that a sphere can be triangulated with three vertices and illustrates the triangulation in Figure 4.9.

Comment: @tempate Although I don't have access to the book you reference, the discrepancy probably has to do with a difference in definitions. The definition of triangulation I used requires that two vertices determine a unique edge, three vertices determine a unique triangle, etc. See Rob Arthan's answer to this question for the decomposition you describe.

Answer (score 8):

A triangulation is a special case of a [regular CW complex decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex#Regular_CW_complexes). Your decomposition with $2$ triangles is not a triangulation but it is a perfectly good regular CW complex.
However there is no such decomposition of the sphere with an odd number of triangles joined edge-to-edge, as the edges would have to be joined in pairs (because the sphere is a surface without boundary). In particular, as Adam Lowrance points out you cannot find a triangulation of the sphere with $3$ triangles.